# Creating a new Conda Environment results in the PackagesNotFoundError for python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda, environment

While creating a new Conda environment (through both the Anaconda Prompt and Pycarm, it errors during the "Solving environment" step with the following "PackagesNotFound" [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1degq.png) for python 3.7. I have uninstalled and reinstalled both Anaconda and Pycharm multiple times, but this error still persists. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1fiw.png) is my current Path variable.

Comment: It looks like the Path is some how not correctly set because the Python executable is not being located. Without more information from you, however, I can't provide much more assistance. I suggest adding more about your process so that we can be more helpful.

Comment: @HaydenEastwood Thank you for your reply. I have updated my question to include my current Path variable. What other information would be helpful?

Comment: In Windows, you will have to set the path to the location where you installed Anaconda3 to (your path doesn't show Anaconda in your path). Do this with something like set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\. I am on Mac OSX so can't attempt to reproduce your problem unfortunately. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: @HaydenEastwood Thank you for your help. I set the PATH variable to my Anaconda installation, and although I'm sure that was also an issue, it didn't solve the PackagesNotFound error. However, I did find that for some reason, my "defaults" anaconda channel was removed. I'm not sure how or why, but it was missing, and upon adding it again, the problem was resolved.

Comment: Pleased to hear it worked out :)